# Definir página principal no IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, deploy

Quando fazemos o deploy no IIS com uma aplicação MVC 5, eu preciso definir a página inicial, certo? No meu caso eu tenho a pasta Views => Home => Index.cshtml. No meu caso, vou em Default Document e como eu coloco todo esse passo para informar a página index? Coloquei assim e não funcionou:

```
/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
```

Também retirei a barra inicial e nada também.

Esse é o erro que está dando:

> Unknown Host
>
> ---
>
> **Description**: Unable to locate the server named "**ache.ruptura**" --- the server does not have a DNS entry. Perhaps there is a misspelling in the server name, or the server no longer exists. Double-check the name and try again.

Answer (score 2):

#### Quando fazemos o deploy no IIS com uma aplicação MVC 5, eu preciso definir a página inicial, certo?

Na verdade não, o ASP.NET MVC controla tudo por rotas. O que você precisa verificar é se ao fazer o deploy da apliação, se você copiou o arquivo `Global.asax` para a pasta da aplicação apontada pelo registro da mesma no IIS.

#### Esse é o erro que está dando:

> Unknown Host
>
> ---
>
> Description: Unable to locate the server named "ache.ruptura" --- the server does not have a DNS entry. Perhaps there is a misspelling in the server name, or the server no longer exists. Double-check the name and try again.

Veja que, "**Unknown Host**" e "**Unable to locate the server named "ache.ruptura"**" significa que há um problema de infra que não está permitindo encontrar o servidor pelo DNS.